# How to install gnome videos(new gnome video playing app, formerly totem)

Tags: gnome, totem

How do I install this (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/top-12-features-gnome-3-12) new gnome videos app?

Answer (score 3):

**Totem**

You can install totem by:

```
sudo apt-get install totem libtotem0
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to install totem, I'm asking how to install gnome videos app